# Error when checking if SqlDataReader column has null value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

One of the guys working on a project with me keeps getting an error when the code trys to validate if SqlDataReader returns a null value in a column. He runs this code:

```
if (!DB_Conn.isConnected()) DB_Conn.Connect();
using (SqlDataReader dr = DB_Conn.QueryDB(query))
{
   if (dr.HasRows && !dr.IsDBNull(0))
   {
       maxID = dr.GetInt32(0);
   }
}
```

But gets an error that Its an invalid attemtp to read when no data is present at the !dr.IsDBNull(0) command.

If i run this same code but i query a different table, it works.

Also, i run both queries and they return the expected null value. The querys are:

```
SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Loan;
SELECT MAX(ID) FROM InternationalSwap;
```

I dont think the querys have any affect on the reason why we are getting this error at one machine and not the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call the [`Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read.aspx) method before trying to access any columns:

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    if (!dr.IsDBNull(0))
        maxID = dr.GetInt32(0);
}
```

But... if you only need a single value then you should probably use something like [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) rather than a datareader.

Comment: This works, but i'm a little confused as to why it worked with me, but then i didn't work at my coworkers computer with practically the same code. Anyway, thanks for the help.